# Transition CSS3 freeze in google Chrome Windows

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, fullpage.js

I'm experiencing a very weird chrome (45 and 46 windows only) behaviour with css3 transition using fullpage.js

The transition "freeze" 80% of the time when I'm going from the first to the second section of a website. And then, everything work fine.

Take a look by yourself :

1. first you will need to login as the website is still under construction. 
   [Http://www.evandorlot.com/wp-login](http://Http://www.evandorlot.com/wp-login)
   Login : **Guest**
   Pass: **Luckyone**

then, come back to the home page [www.evandorlot.com](http://www.evandorlot.com/)

1. Sroll down, here's the bug. From the first to the second slide of the website, the transitions "freeze" they pop instantly to their final stage.
2. After pressing ctrl+f5 and trying again, sometime it work, sometime no... it seams to be a chrome bug as it work 20% of the time. But I would like to fix it somehow. For this I need to know what cause the issue.

I'm working on this bug for more than a week now and don't find any solutions:
I tried to disable all the TweenMax animations, then all the css3 animations that are not vital. I also disabled all my custom javascript expet fullpage.js function without any configuration, I tried removing the image from the second slide, deleting the second slide, swapping the second slide with another, replacing the image, the text, deleting the diamond icon, deleting the menu on the bottom right corner, actiavating GPU acceleration by adding CSS3 `translateZ` to each elements that is animated on the first and second slide... Nothing fixed the bug.

The only way to make it working properly is to empty ALL the content from the second slide and leave the entire section empty. So I guess something cause the issue, but I really don't know what.

I know it's a long shot but if anyone has already experienced similar bug or has a suggestion to fix it. It will be very useful as I'm totally desperate :)

Comment: Oups, the link to login disapeared : www.evandorlot.com/wp-login

Comment: I just have checked the painting frames of your website site first to second slide it's hits huge. It's logging more than 60fps. Hopes that makes us to feel the animation is not happening.

Comment: This is true, I opened a new tread in Chromium about this issue, https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=533953 
On firefox the lowest frame rate I got is 19,76fps.

Comment: I see the jump of second to first slide in the unable to repo video. but you commented as everything went well on that video ????

Comment: I re-watched the video and I just see the bug at 55s (2sec before the end..). I'll notice them. Thanks Krish !

Comment: No news from chrome's dev team... Do you encounter the same issue ?

Comment: Nope. I didn't faced this issue.